# Search in dynamic fields

Tags: solr, solrnet

I have two dynamic fields like "Product-Name-***" **and*** "Product-Rating-*".
One document can contain 5 products and respective ratings like below.

```
<str name="Product-Name-0">HTC Wildfire S</str>
<str name="Product-Name-1">Samsung Tab 2</str>
<str name="Product-Name-2">Samsung Note</str>
<str name="Product-Name-3">IPhone5</str>
<str name="Product-Name-4">Nokia Lumia 720</str>
<int name="Product-Rating-0">5</int>
<int name="Product-Rating-1">9</int>
<int name="Product-Rating-2">7</int>
<int name="Product-Rating-3">9</int>
<int name="Product-Rating-4">9</int>
```

In my current scnario, I have to boost the products which has a higher rating(Only More then 6.Note-Rating will be between 1 to 10).
If i want to search for a perticular product name for example "IPhone5",then i am quering like this

```
(Product-Name-0:IPhone5 AND (Product-Rating-0:7^3 OR Product-Rating-0:8^4 OR Product-Rating-0:9^5 OR Product-Rating-0:10^6)) OR 
(Product-Name-1:IPhone5 AND (Product-Rating-1:7^3 OR Product-Rating-1:8^4 OR Product-Rating-1:9^5 OR Product-Rating-1:10^6)) OR
(Product-Name-2:IPhone5 AND (Product-Rating-2:7^3 OR Product-Rating-2:8^4 OR Product-Rating-2:9^5 OR Product-Rating-2:10^6)) OR
(Product-Name-3:IPhone5 AND (Product-Rating-3:7^3 OR Product-Rating-3:8^4 OR Product-Rating-3:9^5 OR Product-Rating-3:10^6)) OR
(Product-Name-4:IPhone5 AND (Product-Rating-4:7^3 OR Product-Rating-4:8^4 OR Product-Rating-4:9^5 OR Product-Rating-4:10^6))
```

I could have used Product-Name-*:IPhone5 to find all the documents but problem is i dont know how to boost that product according to its respective Product Rating .

Can anybody guide me wheather i am following the right approach or not ?

Or Is there any other approach to achieve this ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you may get a parsing error if you try to use wildcards in the field name (at least it happened for my installation ) 
can you tell us which solr version are you using?

Comment: I am using SOLR 4.0 Alpha.

Comment: Is there a way for converting above query into edismax ?

Answer (score 0):

I think your schema design itself has issues , why are there multiple names and ratings in single document. Ideally each name should be separate document with its own rating, that way you could boost it using some function on rating value itself.

Comment: No umar.it's is just an example schema.As far as i know schema is all fine.You can take an example of a studentinfo like below
<str name="Subject-Name-0">Science</str>
<str name="Subject-Name-1">Maths</str>
<str name="Subject-Name-2">Economics</str>
<str name="Subject-Name-3">History</str>
<str name="Subject-Name-4">Geography</str>
<int name="Subject-Mark-0">50</int>
<int name="Subject-Mark-1">90</int>
<int name="Subject-Mark-2">70</int>
<int name="Subject-Mark-3">90</int>
<int name="Subject-Mark-4">90</int>
If user searches for a subject name,i need to boost those doc which have more marks.